# Query to check for duplicates

Tags: vba, duplicates

The following was written to inform a user if they are entering duplicate information.

It never detects the duplicate, but all else around it works.

The values from debug (for formats etc.) are

```
me.lisAppID = 1
me.dtReviewDate = 10/09/2015
me.txtReviewerName = colin
```

This is the query

```
Dim tmpRS As DAO.Recordset

    Set tmpRS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT TblReview.ReviewID FROM TblReview Where (TblReview.AppID = " & Me.lisAppID & ") And (TblReview.RevDateTime)= #" & Me.dtReviewDate _
    & "# And (TblReview.RevUserID)= '" & Me.txtReviewerName & "'")

    If tmpRS.RecordCount > 0 Then
        MsgBox "Record is a duplicate, it will not be saved", vbOKOnly
        Cancel = 1
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set tmpRS = Nothing
```

Comment: Just checking: have you verified the record actually exists, with a manual query?

Comment: Hi Kenny, I have checked, and due to in app testing there are now 10 matching records.

Comment: Allright, thank you for checking. It's puzzling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some things to try.

1. Explicitly format your date variable when building the sql string:

   ```
   Set tmpRS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT TblReview.ReviewID FROM TblReview Where (TblReview.AppID = " & Me.lisAppID _
       & ") And (TblReview.RevDateTime)= #" & Format(Me.dtReviewDate,"mm/dd/yyyy") _
       & "# And (TblReview.RevUserID)= '" & Me.txtReviewerName & "'")
   ```
2. Consider using the optional parameters in the `OpenRecordset` method. Some types of connection do not actually return a value for the `Recordset.RecordCount` property. From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff821452.aspx):

> The RecordCount property doesn't indicate how many records are contained in a dynaset–, snapshot–, or forward–only–type Recordset object until all records have been accessed.

Comment: Thanks ChipsLetten, Explicit formatting (option one) worked great.